# invalid video link when use literal control

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Please need your help as i store video link in Sql Server
like

I use datatable to get it but when i put it in literal control it gave me in valid link can you please push your help to pass this problem.

C# Code

```
public DataTable Binding_VideoLists()
{
    SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[0];
    Dal.Open();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = Dal.SelectData("Binding_VideoList", null);
    return dt;
}    

DataTable dt = Rpt.Binding_VideoLists();
string Video_Link = dt.Rows[0][3].ToString();
Literal1.Text = Video_Link;
```

Comment: What does `Video_Link` contain?

Comment: <Video width=400 Controls><Source src=video/2.mp4 type=video/mp4></video>

Comment: i past it directly to literal it work good but when i use the past code it gave me invalid link

Comment: The code you posted works then?

Comment: it works very good but still giving me invalid link

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try.

Set the `Mode` property of the `Literal` control to `PassThrough`. This will prevent the contents of the control from being modified.

`Literal1.Mode = LiteralMode.PassThrough;`

The default `Mode` is `Transform`.